# Can I use multiple top level domains for my Github repositories?

Tags: github, dns

I want to have this kind of custom domains setup.

> arunsathiya.github.io = sathiya.me
>  arunsathiya/blog =
>   blog.sathiya.me
>  arunsathiya/project-one = projectone.com
>   arunsathiya/project-two = projecttwo.com

How can I get this done? I need to know proper DNS records for this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to go about this. I added CNAME records for the subdomain. A records for the top level domain with the IP mentioned by Github.

Added the domains to Github repository settings and created CNAME files in the repositories.